# XML element - Formatting Tag

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I am using

```
new XElement("InstdAmt", "1000")
```

However, I would like to add the currency in the first tag as shown below. How could I do this please?

Only using the first tag

```
new XElement("InstdAmt Ccy=EUR", "1000")
```

so I can get this result

```
<InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">1000</InstdAmt>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an attribute:

```
 new XElement("InstdAmt", new XAttribute("Ccy", "Eur"), "1000");
```